# How to install mingw manually?

Tags: gcc, mingw

Once I saw gcc version 4 at [sf.net host page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) of mingw,I managed to download [the whole package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/GCC%20Version%204/Current%20Release_%20gcc-4.4.0/gcc-full-4.4.0-mingw32-bin-2.tar.lzma/download) and install the new package,but it turns out a lot of mistakes(`create process error`while run gcc and give out non-meaningful code) and Now I have to rollback to the orginal automatical installed version.

My question is: is there anyone have successfully installed the mingw(with gcc v4) manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know what you mean by "manually", and I don't know what "sf.net" is. If you want to install MinGW, download from http://tdragon.net/recentgcc - current latest version 4.4.1 - and run the installer. You can install multiple versions - I usually have two or more on the go at once.

If this isn't what you are asking, please clarify your question.

Comment: `manually` means without automated installer,which is limited.

Comment: Use the Twilight Dragon link I posted, also at sourceforge - I have had zero problems with this build, and it is usually ahead of the "official" one. If your problems are with sourceforge itself (and I agree, it is pants) then modify your question to reflect the exact problems you are having.

Comment: "limited" in what sense? It will install a complete working copy of the software. What more do you want?

Comment: not exactly,its not complete and its not the newest.if it is,i will not need to install the newer gcc manually.

Comment: TD 4.4.1 is the latest. And if you think its not complete, what do you think it is missing?

Comment: i mean installation from `MinGW automatic installer` is not complete because it could install only binutils,ada,gcc-core,gcc-g77,gcc-g++,gcc-objc,mingwrt,win32api,make,but not the newest gcc edition,etc.i do not mean TD 4.4.1,which i haven't heard before.

Comment: Well, you have heard of it now - so why not use it? And what do you think is the latest gcc edition? Note that MinGW (whichever build) always lags behind the very cutting edge of GCC - it is a port, not a development.

Comment: Bottom line, if you want to use MinGW with g++ 4.4.x, use the TD build I provided a link to.It works, I've been using it for months. This conversation is now closed, from my side.

Comment: thanks.it works.it seems that manually installaion of mingw is possible since i encouter the same `CreateProcess : no such file` error but after setting the correct PATH,the error gone.